# HtmlAgilityPack get data from Table

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to get the data in columns and rows as on the website but when I get the data down, then it is vertical, now I have to get the data in the table of the website in any way?

I have a table:

```
<div>
    <span id="ctl00_panelContent_ctl01_ucThongTinThiTruong_lblErr"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="ctl00_panelContent_ctl01_ucThongTinThiTruong_grdTT" class="RadGrid RadGrid_Office2007 rgMultiHeader" style="height:700px;width:100%;">

        <div class="rgHeaderWrapper"><div id="ctl00_panelContent_ctl01_ucThongTinThiTruong_grdTT_GridHeader" class="rgHeaderDiv" style="padding-removed16px;overflow:hidden;">

        <table class="rgMasterTable rgClipCells" border="0" id="ctl00_panelContent_ctl01_ucThongTinThiTruong_grdTT_ctl00_Header" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;overflow:hidden;empty-cells:show;">
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width:50px" />
                <col style="width:70px" />
                <col style="width:70px" />
                <col style="width:70px;display:none;" />
                <col style="width:70px;display:none;" />
                <col style="width:70px;display:none;" />
                <col style="width:110px" />
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
```

this's my code:

```
var document = webBrowser1.Document;
var documentAsIHtmlDocument3 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)document.DomDocument;

var htmlString = documentAsIHtmlDocument3.documentElement.innerHTML;

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlString);

// string texts = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='inner']/p").InnerText;
HtmlNodeCollection texts = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='rgMasterTable rgClipCells']");
string kq = "";

if (texts != null)
{


    foreach (var item in texts)
    {
        kq += item.InnerText + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
richTextBox1.Text = kq;

}


}
```

This code works fine but the data obtained is 1 vertical, I want to get data on the website as they do how

Comment: Do you have the link to the page you are fetching the data from?

Comment: it is the internal website should have equal access vpn

Comment: Could you provide the table html with some rows of the actual data?

Comment: it table html in answers

Answer (score 2):

After you get the table

```
HtmlNodeCollection texts = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='rgMasterTable rgClipCells']");
```

You can get the individual rows like this

```
var rows = texts.Descendants("tr").ToList();
```

This will give a list of each row in the table. From there you can iterate through the children nodes and get their values like this

```
List<List<string>> rowValues = new List<List<string>>();
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    List<string> currentRowValues = new List<string>();
    foreach (var column in row.ChildNodes)
    {
        currentRowValues.Add(column.InnerText);
    }
    rowValues.Add(currentRowValues);
}
```

`rowValues` is now a List where each row is represented as a List where the elements of the list are the values of the cells in the row.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr class="rgRow" id="ctl00_panelContent_ctl01_ucThongTinThiTruong_grdTT_ctl00__0" style="color:Black;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;">
        <td align="center" valign="middle" style="width:50px;">1</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;">  16 332</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;">  7 367</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;">  1 298</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;">  7 667</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;">   1</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;">   1</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;">   1</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;display:none;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;display:none;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;display:none;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;">   560</td><td align="left" valign="middle" style="width:110px;white-space:nowrap;">GT5:NHON_TRACH_2</td><td align="left" valign="middle" style="width:110px;white-space:nowrap;">GT5:NHON_TRACH_2</td><td align="left" valign="middle" style="width:110px;white-space:nowrap;">GT5:NHON_TRACH_2</td>
    </tr><tr class="rgAltRow" id="ctl00_panelContent_ctl01_ucThongTinThiTruong_grdTT_ctl00__1" style="color:Black;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;">
        <td align="center" valign="middle" style="width:50px;">2</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;"><span>  15 852</span><img src="Images/Grid/down.bmp" style="border-width:0px;" /></td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;"><span>  7 157</span><img src="Images/Grid/down.bmp" style="border-width:0px;" /></td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;"><span>  1 477</span><img src="Images/Grid/up.bmp" style="border-width:0px;" /></td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;"><span>  7 218</span><img src="Images/Grid/down.bmp" style="border-width:0px;" /></td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;">   1</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;">   1</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;">   1</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;display:none;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;display:none;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;display:none;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;">   560</td><td align="left" valign="middle" style="width:110px;white-space:nowrap;">GT5:NHON_TRACH_2</td><td align="left" valign="middle" style="width:110px;white-space:nowrap;">GT5:NHON_TRACH_2</td><td align="left" valign="middle" style="width:110px;white-space:nowrap;">GT5:NHON_TRACH_2</td>
    </tr><tr class="rgRow" id="ctl00_panelContent_ctl01_ucThongTinThiTruong_grdTT_ctl00__2" style="color:Black;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;">
        <td align="center" valign="middle" style="width:50px;">3</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;"><span>  15 575</span><img src="Images/Grid/down.bmp" style="border-width:0px;" /></td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;"><span>  6 853</span><img src="Images/Grid/down.bmp" style="border-width:0px;" /></td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;"><span>  1 411</span><img src="Images/Grid/down.bmp" style="border-width:0px;" /></td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;"><span>  7 311</span><img src="Images/Grid/up.bmp" style="border-width:0px;" /></td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;">   1</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;">   1</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;">   1</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;display:none;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;display:none;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;display:none;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:70px;">   560</td><td align="left" valign="middle" style="width:110px;white-space:nowrap;">GT5:NHON_TRACH_2</td><td align="left" valign="middle" style="width:110px;white-space:nowrap;">GT5:NHON_TRACH_2</td><td align="left" valign="middle" style="width:110px;white-space:nowrap;">GT5:NHON_TRACH_2</td>
```

Comment: You should add your updates as edits to your original question, not as answers.

Answer (score -1):

Data table from website:

```
hour     nation     North Central   South North Central South System
1         16 332    7 367   1 298   7 667   1      1    1       560
2         15 852    7 157   1 477   7 218   1      1    1       560
3         15 575    6 853   1 411   7 311   1      1    1       560
4         15 466    6 839   1 458   7 168   1      1    1       560 
5         15 968    6 969   1 608   7 391   0      1    1       560
```

Data i get from website

```
1
16 332
7 367
1 298
7 667
1
1
1
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
560
2
15 852
7 157
1 477
7 218
1
1
1



560
3
15 575
6 853
1 411
7 311
1
1
1



560
15 466
6 839
1 458
7 168
1
1
1



560
```